# Classification of Sheaves of Q-modules over R

Tags: sheaf-theory

Every constructible sheaf of $\mathbb{Q}-$modules over $\mathbb{R}$ is the direct sum of indecomposable sheaves, which are either sheaves with stalk $\mathbb{Q}$ at a point or constant sheaves with stalk $\mathbb{Q}$ on an open interval extended by lower ! or lower * at each endpoint. What happens if we remove the 'constructible' hypothesis? Is there a similar classification?

Comment: Are you looking for something that says, roughly, that the category of sheaves over $\mathbb R$ is a "limit" of the categories of constructible sheaves with respect to a given stratification? Here, the "limit" should be taken with respect to the poset of stratifications of $\mathbb R$.